# Sql error in Cakephp2 FindBy statement, getting a 1064 syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

*EDIT: Its **f**indBy, thank you to the commenter who corrected me"

So Im running a server script in Cakephp 2 that handles information in the "Bonuses" area of the app.

```
 $objAccount = $this->Account->FindById($Bonus['Account']['id']);
```

Theres the exact code that sends the error off.  Its in the BonusesComponent, which otherwise works.

```
</pre>Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FindById' at line 1
#0 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(436): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(403): DboSource->_execute('FindById', Array)
#2 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(646): DboSource->execute('FindById', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php(588): DboSource->fetchAll('FindById', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(776): DboSource->query('FindById', Array, Object(Account))
#5 /var/www/secondcake/app/Controller/Component/BonusesComponent.php(525): Model->__call('FindById', Array)
#6 /var/www/secondcake/app/Controller/Component/BonusesComponent.php(525): Account->FindById('83')
#7 /var/www/secondcake/app/Console/Command/CronTradeBonusesShell.php(24): BonusesComponent->EndBonus(Array)
#8 /var/www/secondcake/app/Console/Command/CronTradeBonusesShell.php(10): CronTradeBonusesShell->EndTradeBonuses()
#9 /var/www/secondcake/app/Console/Command/cronBase.php(105): CronTradeBonusesShell->cronMain()
#10 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php(389): CronBase->main()
#11 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(177): Shell->runCommand(NULL, Array)
#12 /var/www/secondcake/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(69): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/secondcake/app/Console/cake.php(33): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
```

Heres the stack trace.

Just to add, if anyone has any ideas about *why* this is doing this, I'd be very grateful.  The FindBy methods work fine all over the app.

Comment: trying to check the query `var_dump($this->Account->getDataSource()->showLog());`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was because you had a typo in the function call.

CakePHP2 use a magic function `__call` to map any call to model. If you take a look at `Model::__call` you can see that it send the function name to every behavior to see if one behavior has a corresponding function. If the function does not exist, it send it directly to the data source as a request.

If you get a SQL Error in CakePHP2 with a query corresponding to the name of a function, you may want to directly check that you did not mistype the function name.